# Send associative array using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The following associative array need to be send to php using:

```
getsz[Action]="Save";
getsz[Email]="asd@asd.sad";
getsz[Gender]="male"
```

but rather recieving the needed format The result at php end was:

```
Array(
[0] => Save
[1] => asd@asd.sad
[2] => male)
```

I have sent data using phpliveX library.

```js
  getuserdata.saveuserdata(getalsz,{onUpdate:function(response,root){               }});
```

where getuserdata is ajaxified object of class to which saveuserdata function belongs.

I want to achieve this result

```
    Array(
[Action] => Save
[Email] => asd@asd.sad
[Gender] => male)
```

Edit: getuserdata is object 
saveuserdata is function of class to which the object getuserdata

```
function saveuserdata($userdata)
{print_r($userdata);
}
```

Comment: Please add getuserdata function.

Comment: @NimatullahRazmjo The details has been added